# Previously deleted node/console script names still showing with ros2 run

Tags: ros, ros2, setup.py

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I initially made an error when editing my setup.py file (missed a comma I think) and when I used tab/auto completion with the ros2 run command, I was getting an incorrectly named node. However, despite editing the setup.py file and using colcon build, I still have the same issue. I initially thought it may have been due to how I added the new node (meant for ArUco tag detection) in the 'console script' section and edited that but it made no difference. As a result, now I have several options coming up with ros2 run even though they are incorrect.

I am using ROS2 Foxy on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, would really appreciate any help.

This is my current setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup

package_name = 'tb3_obj_detection'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='___',
    maintainer_email='____@todo.todo',
    description='TODO: Package description',
    license='TODO: License declaration',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'img_publisher = tb3_obj_detection.camera_pub:main',
            'img_subscriber = tb3_obj_detection.camera_sub:main',
            'hand_detector = tb3_obj_detection.hand_detection:main',
            'hand_detector_tflite = tb3_obj_detection.hand_detection_tflite:main',
            'aruco_detection = tb3_obj_detection.aruco_detection:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

This is the output I get when trying to use ros2 run after sourcing my workspace,
(https://ibb.co/L8dwDKW)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402262/previously-deleted-node/console-script-names-still-showing-with-ros2-run/) by [Reuben](https://answers.ros.org/users/100232/reuben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you try `colcon build --cmake-clean-cache`? You can try deleting the `build` and `inc` folders, then rebuild your workspace and source it again with `source ~/dev_ws/install/setup.bash`.

---

Also add the result of `ros2 wtf`/`ros2 doctor` if the above doesn't help.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reuben](https://answers.ros.org/users/100232/reuben/) on 2022-06-13**:
Deleting the build & install folders and rebuilding the workspace worked! Thank you ljaniec